# Subsurface light flickering with a cycles rendering engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise, subsurface-scattering

I got a problem with lanterns in my rendering scene, and I noticed flickering in the lights in my video. I can't try to render with more samples since 25 samples already took me 5 hours. The flickering is mainly in subsurface parts. I got the denoiser turned on as
[image]

Is it something due to my lack of samples or the denoiser? How can I fix it in the video file if it lacks samples?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! can you try share a link to the video? maybe youtube or dropbox link

Comment: I forgot to mention that the light isn't turning on and off, but it's the color in the center changing more brighter in some areas and less brighter in other areas over time, and the frequency is very fast

Comment: This flickering is way more apparent on more giant screens and the problem became huge

Comment: There might be different reasons coming together, but I guess the low sample rate especially in combination with denoising. But for the render time: are you rendering with CPU or GPU? And the _Denoiser_ settings you show are the ones for _Viewport_, not for _Render_.

Comment: I'm using the Apple M1 GPU, and I've checked the Render one: OpenImageDenoise, Albedo and Normal, and Accurate.